# Alternative for using multiple callouts from Salesforce to external System

Tags: platform-cache

We retrieve a list of flight passengers from an external system via a callout. The endpoint sends us a passenger list along with arrival and departure airport codes. Our external system has another endpoint that translates airport codes to their names. We would like to retrieve the airport name based on its code in order to send an email with flight information (incl. airport name) to the user.

I am little wary of calling out to the external system every time we need to translate an airport code to its corresponding name.

Assuming the mapping of codes to names won't change that often, how do I avoid multiple callouts?

I was thinking of these options:

1. Platform Cache. Load all airport codes and city names into cache and then do probably a monthly retrieve
2. An external object. Need to check if they have required adapter to connect the database.
3. Custom metadata to store code/name mappings.

Just to add: If the external system does not have the endpoint to query all the airport names and only have endpoint where they expect a set of airport codes,how should we go about it then?

Comment: Thanks @identigral. How long will the key values stay active in cache?

Comment: Up to 48 hrs. Check the [Cache Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_cache/platform_cache_use) for more details.

Comment: This is a classic cache use case (option 1)

Comment: So this is how it should be implemented: once the event comes,get the flightId,make a a callout and get the passengerinfo, from that info prepare a set of < Airport codes> check if the those codes exist in cache(it should ideally be there for 24 hours),if not call out and load the cache with the map of airport codes and airport names and populate your template with the names.

Comment: Yes. In addition to event-based call to cache, you can populate the cache in an async process (a batch job, for example). [CacheBuilder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_builder.htm) is a useful abstraction.

Comment: @identigral Unfortunately,external system does not have an endpoint where we can retrieve all the airport names(9000+),they only accept a list of Ids.Hence use of cache wont be appropriate it seems?What could be the best approach in this case now? making a callout everytime i receive an event?

Comment: Send them all IDs in one call or succession of calls (if there are limits on payload size/etc) and cache the entire list. This data is publicly available: https://openflights.org/data.html or https://ourairports.com/data/ .

Comment: Thank you for your help.So we should have a batch job to populate the cache say every 2 days(Since org cache has a ttl of 48 hours)with a callout having a list of IDs (may be in succession).All these Ids(IATACode) will need to passed in the callout. Later when a new airport is added(even if i do it with CMD),we will need to modify our code,to add the new iata code. Isn't it better I go with individual callouts every time?

Comment: No, it's not better. You want to populate the cache asynchronously. If you don't care about performance, you can make a callout every time.